# DriveType function in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am having problem with this code to compare Driver.Name with a string in my resource like :
 if Driver.Name = "D:\" then do something and this is my code :

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For Each drive As IO.DriveInfo In IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()
            If drive.DriveType = DriveType.Fixed Then
                If drive.IsReady = True Then
                    ' this is the list in my resource
                    '"D:\"|"E:\"|"F:\"|"G:\"|"H:\"|"L:\"|"K:\"|"M:\"|"O:\"|
                    For Each word As String In My.Resources.String1.Split(CChar("|"))
                        If word.ToString.Contains(drive.Name) Then
                            MsgBox("One Driver Found")
                        Else
                            MsgBox("No Driver Found")
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `I am having problem` is not very descriptive.

Comment: this code return always MsgBox("No Driver Found")

Comment: Please take a moment to read this *carefully*: [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your resource string

From this

```
'"D:\"|"E:\"|"F:\"|"G:\"|"H:\"|"L:\"|"K:\"|"M:\"|"O:\"|
```

To this

```
'"D:\|E:\|F:\|G:\|H:\|L:\|K:\|M:\|O:\|"
```

Comment: Still the same . It didn't change

Comment: Do you ACTUALLY have any of the drives listed in the resource string? I Tried it and it works fine and displays the correct messages.

Comment: Is your D:\ drive of FIXED type? (like an internal HDD) or is it REMOVABLE? (like a CD/DVD)